# Htaccess covert uppercase to lowercase and redirect html to PHP page

Tags: .htaccess

I have the functionality to direct HTML pages to those matching PHP page names

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).html $1.php [L,NC]
```

This works fine if I type an url such us www.example.com/privacy.html (privacy.php is the page being rendered)

The second requirement is to convert uppercase to lowercase url So I added this code in my http.conf

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteMap lc int:tolower 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z] 
RewriteRule (.*) ${lc:$1} [R=301,L]
```

and this code in htaccess CheckSpelling on

The covertion from uppercase to lowercase works but now

```
www.example.com/PRIVACY.html
```

becomes

```
www.example.com/privacy.php
```

If I type `www.example.com/privacy.html` still works. url does not change

I would like to keep the url ending in .html Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to httpd.conf, try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteMap lowercase int:tolower
RewriteCond $1 [A-Z]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /${lowercase:$1} [R=301,L]
```

If you only have access to .htaccess then this will work - takes a bit longer to re-direct then httpd.conf but does the trick.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# If there are caps, set HASCAPS to true and skip next rule
RewriteRule [A-Z] - [E=HASCAPS:TRUE,S=1]

# Skip this entire section if no uppercase letters in requested URL
RewriteRule ![A-Z] - [S=28]

# Replace single occurance of CAP with cap, then process next Rule.
RewriteRule ^([^A]*)A(.*)$ $1a$2
RewriteRule ^([^B]*)B(.*)$ $1b$2
RewriteRule ^([^C]*)C(.*)$ $1c$2
RewriteRule ^([^D]*)D(.*)$ $1d$2
RewriteRule ^([^E]*)E(.*)$ $1e$2
RewriteRule ^([^F]*)F(.*)$ $1f$2
RewriteRule ^([^G]*)G(.*)$ $1g$2
RewriteRule ^([^H]*)H(.*)$ $1h$2
RewriteRule ^([^I]*)I(.*)$ $1i$2
RewriteRule ^([^J]*)J(.*)$ $1j$2
RewriteRule ^([^K]*)K(.*)$ $1k$2
RewriteRule ^([^L]*)L(.*)$ $1l$2
RewriteRule ^([^M]*)M(.*)$ $1m$2
RewriteRule ^([^N]*)N(.*)$ $1n$2
RewriteRule ^([^O]*)O(.*)$ $1o$2
RewriteRule ^([^P]*)P(.*)$ $1p$2
RewriteRule ^([^Q]*)Q(.*)$ $1q$2
RewriteRule ^([^R]*)R(.*)$ $1r$2
RewriteRule ^([^S]*)S(.*)$ $1s$2
RewriteRule ^([^T]*)T(.*)$ $1t$2
RewriteRule ^([^U]*)U(.*)$ $1u$2
RewriteRule ^([^V]*)V(.*)$ $1v$2
RewriteRule ^([^W]*)W(.*)$ $1w$2
RewriteRule ^([^X]*)X(.*)$ $1x$2
RewriteRule ^([^Y]*)Y(.*)$ $1y$2
RewriteRule ^([^Z]*)Z(.*)$ $1z$2

# If there are any uppercase letters, restart at very first RewriteRule in file.
RewriteRule [A-Z] - [N]

RewriteCond %{ENV:HASCAPS} TRUE
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

You can read more from [askapache.com](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/rewrite-uppercase-lowercase.html)